# Are gravitational waves the slowest waves known to science?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

Consider that two celestial bodies orbit have a frequency of one rotation every 50,000 years, it means that the periodicity of the gravitational wave sensed by a distant observer is about 50k years. Can a wave in the electromagnetic wavelengths feasibly have the same frequency?

Comment: Note that [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) and [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) are not the same thing; presumably you meant the latter.

Comment: In principle, putting a small positive charge on one of the the celestial bodies you mentioned and a corresponding negative charge on the other would create EM waves of that same wavelength.  Does that count as "feasible"?

Comment: Some times I take a rope and create waves in it. Those are pretty slow — definitely slower than gravitational waves. ;)

Comment: We did the same with a water hose, you can hop over the hose between the waves. The moon-earth alignment generates longer waves than your rope, waves about 100 AU's. and the tilt of the planets indicates that planet 9 affects us with gravity oscillations which repeat after the previous peak is 50,000 light years away, because it's period is probably around 50k years.

Answer (score 2):

To the question in the title: gravitational waves move at light speed.

A frequency of once per 50000 years gives a wavelength of $6\times 10^{20}$ m. This is much smaller than the size of the universe, so yes, such EM waves are possible.